When/Once/As soon as/After the rain [stops]/[has stopped]
Suppose it's raining. John and Samantha are standing at the window, watching the raindrops falling on the ledge. John says to her:
1. When the rain [stops]/[has stopped], I'll call Peter, and we'll all go hiking in the forest.
2. Once the rain [stops]/[has stopped], I'll call Peter, and we'll all go hiking in the forest.
3. As soon as the rain [stops]/[has stopped], I'll call Peter, and we'll all go hiking in the forest.
4. After the rain [stops]/[has stopped], I'll call Peter, and we'll all go hiking in the forest.
Which tense would you use in the above examples: the simple present or the present perfect? Thank you.

This question is similar to: The present perfect tense describing a future event?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
To talk about situations and conditions that are repeated or predictable, we can use either if or when + present verb form
We don’t use when to introduce possible or unreal situations:

stops=is the correct usage except the first sentence. But if you're speaking about an activity that you've done repeatedly, you could use present perfect. “I've cleaned up many times after a party,” but not for just a one-time event.

"When the rain stops, I'll call Peter" - what's wrong with that?

You might get more useful answers if you elaborate on why you thought there might be some difference.

You can use either one, and there's no difference in meaning.
Personally, I would use stops in every example, but that might be an American English perspective on the answer.
